# Neo4j Cypher query for many to many relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have a graph that looks like the following:

```
Brand--SOLD_BY-->Store
```

One brand of a certain item can be sold by multiple stores. Similarly, a single store can sell multiple brands of items.

What I want to achieve is find all the stores that sell a particular brand but in the result along with the store, I would also like the other brands that are sold by that particular store.

For example:

Brand1 is sold by StoreA, StoreB, StoreC. The result should look something like..

StoreA - Brand1, Brand2

StoreB - Brand1, Brand3

StoreC - Brand1

I've managed to find the stores but I'm not being able to find the other brands sold by the store.

```
MATCH (b:Brand)-[s:SOLD_BY]->(s:Store)
WHERE b.id=1
WITH DISTINCT s AS stores
RETURN stores
```

One thing I've thought of is if I should loop inside the collected stores and find the brands but I don't know how efficient that would be since the graph can have many nodes.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this query :

```
MATCH (:Brand {id:1})-[:SOLD_BY]->(s:Store)
RETURN s, [ (b)-[:SOLD_BY]->(s) | b] AS brands
```

See this link to have more information : https://neo4j.com/blog/cypher-graphql-neo4j-3-1-preview/

Cheers

Comment: Whoops, I think you meant to use `b` to populate your pattern comprehension instead of `s`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! It worked like a charm. A quick question I would like to ask - How efficient will this query be if I have say like more than 10000 nodes? I assume the pattern comprehension loops over every node so I was wondering if that would make the process slow for a large number of nodes. Thanks again.

Comment: If you have a unique constraint on `:Brand(id)`, the execution time will only depends of the rels density between `Brand` & `Store`.