# How to create a one-many relationship in neo4j using cypher query language

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to create relationship between retailers and products sold by the retailers. For example if the store "xyz" sells products item1, item2 and item3, I would like to create a relationship "SELLS_PRODUCTS" between them from store to the product.

Here is my sample code: 
Here Retailers is the retailers table, and Products is another table which has both the common details like the productname,storename etc which is required for the relationship.

```
MATCH (r:Retailers{Name: "Prestige Liquor Store"})
WITH r
MATCH (p:Products)
WHERE r.ProductproductName = p.ProductName
CREATE UNIQUE (r)-[:SELLS_PRODUCTS]->(p)
```

Comment: Can you clarify how you have multiple products stored for the retailer? The last MATCH and WHERE shows you're referencing a single property of your :Retailer node, `r.ProductproductName`, so I can't see how this could refer to multiple products.

Comment: I am trying something like to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45392402/neo4j-cypher-query-for-many-to-many-relationship

Comment: Yes, but the the issue is this: `WHERE r.ProductproductName = p.ProductName`. How is this single property on a single :Retailers node supposed to relate to multiple products? Is this a list property?

Comment: Instead of me as an amateur asking the way to solve this, can you give me a correct example to create a one-many relationship.

Comment: Looks like cybersam has this one. I had assumed the data model implied by the query was already populated to some degree, and that this question was about how to use existing data on nodes to create the relationships, thus the questions for clarification. I may have gotten ahead of myself there.

Comment: Thanks InverseFalcon. You are always there for me when it comes to neo4j.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's say each `Retailer` node contains a `productNames` list, and each `Product` node has a `name`. For example:

```
CREATE (:Retailer {name: 'Prestige Liquor Store', productNames: ['a', 'b', 'c']})
CREATE (:Product {name: 'b', price: 12.50}),
       (:Product {name: 'c', price: 99.95});
```

Then this query would ensure that the "Prestige Liquor Store" has a unique `SELLS` relationship to each of the `Product`s it sells (that are in the DB):

```
MATCH (r:Retailer {name: "Prestige Liquor Store"})
MATCH (p:Product)
WHERE p.name IN r.productNames
MERGE (r)-[:SELLS]->(p);
```

Also, if you create indexes for `:Retailer(name)` and `Product(name)`, that should greatly speed up the above query if there are many retailers and/or products.

Comment: Hello CyberSam. But If I create another retailer that also sells the same product but the query to create relation will also add that node too to this retailer. So how can we solve this?

Comment: Not clear on what you are stating. If you modified the above query by replacing "Prestige Liquor Store" with the name of the other retailer, there is no way that the query would add any relationships to the "Prestige Liquor Store" retailer.

Comment: For  Example If there are 100 retailers who sell the same products with the same price, this relationship matches the retailer to all the products in the table rather than the products which it sells. I hope you are getting the point. Is there any way to prevent this mapping and create a relationship from the retailers to the products which are sold by the same retailer.

Comment: Are you saying that you want 100 `Product` nodes for the same product, one per retailer selling the same product? That is probably not what you should be doing. You should try to keep a single `Product` node per product, and store the retailer-specific data for each product elsewhere (like in the relationship between each retailer and the product).

Comment: Sure cybersam. I will do that and update you. But I think I got a direction.